# Azure Event Hub Issue

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have a Nodejs app which send messages to event hub and event triggered send messages to my function app which get this messages  and store into cosmosDB.

Now the problem is whenever a new message trigger to event hub it's send all previous messages with new message to function app and result is it's store duplicate messages to  cosmosDB. I have created Azure function app using C#.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This is rather unclear and is likely to close in its present state. Please edit it to add as much relevant detail, configuration and code as you can.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I receive only one new message in Azure function when function triggered. Do you mind using [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/SampleSender) to send event and showing the function log?

Comment: Please provide the code to reproduce the issue